# Operator-> transistency and shared_ptr

Tags: c++

I recall reading somewhere, can't recall where though, that operator-> is transient. That it will look through objects with operator-> until it find something that isn't a pointer and then running a normal operator. on that. I have however run into a problem with this,

Consider this code:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    Foo(int val) : i(val) {}
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Foo> ptr;
    int i;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    typedef std::vector<Foo::ptr> FooVec;
    FooVec v;
    for(FooVec::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout <<it->i <<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
ptr.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
ptr.cpp:15:19: error: ‘class boost::shared_ptr<Foo>’ has no member named ‘i’
   std::cout <<it->i <<std::endl;
```

Since a boost::shared_ptr isn't a pointer. I could solve this by instead writing

```
std::cout <<(*it)->i <<std::endl
```

But I think that looks a lot worse, I tried std::shared_ptr as well but that got the same problem. Is there a nice way of solving this or am I stuck with `(*it)->i`?

Comment: You are stuck. You need to de-reference the iterator *and* the smart pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza Shame, thanks for the quick reply. So are people dereferencing things all over the place or structuring their code another way?

Comment: People shouldn't use pointers "all over the place" anyway. This includes smart pointers. Using smart pointers "all over the place" is only slightly better than using raw pointers all over the place IMO. Using dynamic allocation needlessly doesn't become intrinsically better by switching to a smart pointer class.

Comment: You can make the loop less verbose by using a range-baser for loop. But this only applies if you want to iterate over the whole range.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Agreed, "all over the place" was a bad expression.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ah, didn't think of those. They'll make the code a bit nicer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I recall reading somewhere, can't recall where though, that operator->
>   is transient.

Not in C++.  You'll need to double-dereference as you already discovered.